# How to write a generic extension method which wraps object in an enumerable?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension method which accepts an object of type `T` and returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

Here's my first attempt:

```
internal static class ObjectExtensions<T>
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Yield(this T item)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

This function works, but only if I write `ObjectExtensions<Foo>.Yield(foo)`: `foo.Yield()` doesn't resolve.

*Is there a way to declare an extension method which returns a generic based on the type of the input?*

(I've since discovered `Enumerable.Repeat` meets my original requirements, so this question is more curiosity.)

Comment: take the generics off the class. Only your methods needs be Generic

Comment: The code you have shouldn't compile.  Extension methods cannot be in generic classes, and the compiler should error out with a message saying that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to specify the class as generic, only the extention method.

```
internal static class ObjectExtensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<T> Yield<T>(this T item)
   {
        yield return item;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why I forgot to try that. Thanks!